# How to combine multiple delete fileTree gradle tasks into single one

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

I have the following Gradle task to delete files which are in different directories and with different patterns

```
task cleanNodeCertFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree("node_modules/sub_dir1").matching {
        include "**/*.key"
    }

    delete fileTree("node_modules/sub_dir1").matching {
        include "**/*.txt"
    }

    delete fileTree("node_modules/sub_dir2").matching {
        include "**/*.key"
    }

    delete fileTree("node_modules/sub_dir2").matching {
        include "**/*.txt"
    }

}
```

Is there a way to optimize these 4 delete fileTree commands into 2 or 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I get you right but you can do this with multiple includes:

```
task cleanNodeCertFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree("node_modules").matching {
        include "sub_dir1/**/*.key"
        include "sub_dir1/**/*.txt"
        include "sub_dir2/**/*.key"
        include "sub_dir2/**/*.txt"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bender316. I was looking for the same.